# Initialize common variables used in mutiple classes Python

Tags: python, class, variables

Assuming that I have two classes A and B. In class A, B's instances will created. Both of their instance methods will use a common variable, which is initialized in class A. I have to pass the common_var through the **init** function. Think that if I have classes A, B, C, D.... and common_var1, var2, var3...where all vars have to be passed through class to class, that’s terrible:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, variable_part):
        self.common_var = "Fixed part" +　variable_part
        self.bList = []

    def add_B(self):
        self.bList += [B(self.common_var)]

    def use_common_var():
        do_something(self.common_var)

class B:
    def __init__(self, common_var):
        self.common_var = common_var

    def use_common_var():
        do_something(self.common_var)
```

There's an ugly approach to use **global** here:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, variable_part):
        global common_var
        common_var = "Fixed part" +　variable_part

    def use_common_var(self):
        do_something(common_var)

class B:
    def use_common_var(self):
        do_something(common_var)
```

But I don't think it's a good idea, any better ideas?

### Update:

The original question is here:

The common_vars are a series of prefixes of strings, things like `"https://{}：{}/rest/v1.5/".format(host, port)`, `"mytest"` etc..

and in class A, I use

```
"https://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/v1.5/interface01" and "mytest_a"
```

in class B, I use

```
"https://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/v1.5/interface02" and "mytest_b"
```

in class C, I may use

```
"https://127.0.0.1:8080/rest/v1.5/get?name=123" and "mytest_c"
```

things like that, I use common variables just to multiplex `'https://{}:{}/rest/v1.5'` and `"mytest"` part and none of these A, B, C classes is in "is-a" relationship. But the core part of this problem is the common_var is not common at very first but initialized in one of this class..

---

### Final Update

I compromised. I added a **Helper** class to reuse the common values:

```
class Helper:
    @staticmethod
    def setup(url, prefix):
        Helper.COMMON_URL = url
        Helper.prefix = prefix

# A always initiates first
Class A: 
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        Helper.setup(
            "https://{0}:{1}/rest/v1.5".format(host, port),
            "test"
        )

    def use_common_var():
        do_something(Helper.url, Helper.prefix)


class B:
    def use_common_var():
        do_somesthing(Helper.url, Helper.prefix)


class C:
    def use_common_var():
        do_something(Helper.url, Helper.prefix)
```

Is this a better way?

Comment: I disagree with your "that's terrible" assertion.  This seems normal to me, it's a pretty natural way to handle initializing objects, especially if you want two `A` objects with different `common_var`s to behave predictably.  Could you add `C` and `D` to your example to showcase why you think this would get out of hand?

Comment: I updated the question, please check out.@PatrickHaugh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have four classes that share the same set of four attributes, then you *might* (or not) have a use for inheritance - but this really depends on how/whatfor those attributes are used and what's the real relationship between those classes are. Inheritance is a "is a" relationship (if B inherits from A then B "is a" A too).

Another solution - if you don't really have a "is a" relationship - is to create a class that regroup those four attributes and pass an instance of this class where it's needed. Here again, it only makes sense if there is a real semantic relationshop between those attributes.

Oh and yes, using globals is usually not the solution (unless those variables are actually pseudo-constants - set once at startup and never changed by anyone).

To make a long story short: there's no one-size-fits-all answer to your question, the appropriate solution depends on your concrete use case.

EDIT:

given your added explanation, it looks lik the "cargo class" solution (grouping all your "shared" attributes in a same object)  *might* be what you want. Just beware that it will couple all your classes to this class, which might or not be a problem (wrt/ testing and maintainability). If the forces that drive your A / B ∕ C /D classes evolution are mostly the same then you should be good...

Comment: @Spike that's still not enough to tell for sure which design would make sense for you, but from what you say the "cargo class" solution might make sense.